# InsertRecord return false but seems no error happend

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am new to qt sql, and the problem happening in QSqlRelationalModel puzzled me too much.

Model construtor:

```
RecordTableModel::RecordTableModel(QSharedPointer<BookTableModel> bookTableModel, QObject *parent)
    : QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent), BookTable(BookTableModel)
{
    setTable("record");
    select();

    setRelation(fieldName::genre, QSqlRelation("genres", "id", "genre"));
    setRelation(fieldName::recordState, QSqlRelation("recordStates", "id", "state"));

    /*test start*/
    addEntry(0);
    /*test end*/
}
```

addEntry:

```
int RecordTableModel::addEntry(int bookId)
{
    QSqlRecord record = this->record();
    QSqlRecord bookRecord = bookTable->getRecord(bookId);

    //modify record
    record.setValue(fieldName::bookId, bookRecord.value(BookTableModel::fieldName::bookId));
    record.setValue(fieldName::bookName, bookRecord.value(BookTableModel::fieldName::bookName));
    record.setValue(fieldName::author, bookRecord.value(BookTableModel::fieldName::author));
    //... others same like this

    if (!insertRecord(-1, record)) {
        qDebug() << lastError() << "fail to insert record in addEntry function";
    }

    submitAll();
}
```

In the test the console shows the message above but lastError() contains no error message. And actually the record is inserted into table successfully. Could anyone help solving the problem?

Comment: `QSqlTableModel::insertRecord` does not set the last error.

Comment: @scopchanov Thanks for reply. But how can I get the error message to solve the problem?